# Use separate interface file with PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt

I have an interface file generated from QtDesigner that I want to keep the same in case of changes.

Have a main file called `application.py` handle all the functions, and one file strictly for interface stuff.

I am using **PyQt5**.

I have not been able to find any tutorials on this specific question, any pointers would be helpful.

**Code from `YatsiInterface.py` (shorten)**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_YatsiWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, YatsiWindow):
        YatsiWindow.setObjectName("YatsiWindow")
        YatsiWindow.resize(800, 516)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Terraria.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        YatsiWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.windowLayout = QtWidgets.QWidget(YatsiWindow)
        self.windowLayout.setObjectName("windowLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.windowLayout)
        self.quitButton.setObjectName("quitButton")
        self.buttonsLeftLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        YatsiWindow.setCentralWidget(self.windowLayout)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(YatsiWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        YatsiWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(YatsiWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(YatsiWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, YatsiWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        YatsiWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("YatsiWindow", "Yatsi - Server Interface"))
        self.quitButton.setText(_translate("YatsiWindow", "Quit"))
```

How can I use `self.quitButton.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit())` with the above code? I know to import the file with `from YatsiInterface import Ui_YatsiWindow` but I'm in the dark as how to create button functions without editing the interface file.

**Edit:**

I'll add my broken code below.

```
import sys
from YatsiInterface import Ui_YatsiWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
YatsiWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_YatsiWindow()

ui.setupUi(YatsiWindow)
# Here's the bad part
ui.setupUi.btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
# Up there ^

YatsiWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the way to connect the signal

```
ui.quitButton.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
```

That being said, you probably don't want to do this.  You should probably connect to the `.close` method of the window.  When the window closes, by default, Qt will exit the event loop and quit.

```
ui.quitButton.clicked.connect(YatsiWindow.close)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Solution was so simple, and quick but yet so easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
from YatsiInterface import Ui_YatsiWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

class my_application(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_YatsiWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(my_application, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.my_mythod)

    def my_method(self):
        pass #all your code for the buttons clicked signal

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = my_application()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This my_application class is inheriting your user interface class. Now, you can write your button related functions without editing the user interface file.

```
self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

this will close your user interface when button is clicked.